# Conforming objects to Another object_like 3ds max Freeform Tool

Tags: modeling

How to conform an object to another object like in 3ds max in the Freeform tab.

You can select a ref mesh that the active object is constrained to. If I move a vert in this setting it will conform to the ref mesh. If the ref mesh is open and I try to move a vert past an open area, I can't. Very good for precision.

Is there and tool equivalent to that in Blender or does retopoflow offer that?

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Describe in detail what the desired result is, supported by [reference images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for review so it can be reopened.